# Parallel applications on Nexus 4 - cpufreq drivers?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I was trying to run parallel applications (pbzip2, pigz) from inside of "ubuntu_chroot shell", however I do not see any speedup from their sequential counterparts (bzip2, gzip).

I tried to install cpufrequtils, however I am seeing following errors during installation and use:

Installation:

```
Unpacking cpufrequtils (from .../cpufrequtils_008-1_armhf.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up cpufrequtils (008-1) ...
 * Loading cpufreq kernel modules...                                     [ OK ]
 * CPUFreq Utilities: Setting ondemand CPUFreq governor...                       
 * CPU0...                                                                       
 * CPU1...                                                                         
 * CPU2...                                                                       
 * CPU3...                                                               [fail]
```

Running cpufreq-info:

```
phablet@localhost:~/test$ cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: msm
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 0.00 ms.
  hardware limits: 384 MHz - 1.51 GHz
  available frequency steps: 384 MHz, 486 MHz, 594 MHz, 702 MHz, 810 MHz, 918 MHz, 1.03 GHz, 1.13 GHz, 1.24 GHz, 1.35 GHz, 1.46 GHz, 1.51 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: interactive, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 384 MHz and 1.51 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 384 MHz.
  cpufreq stats: 384 MHz:89.53%, 486 MHz:0.56%, 594 MHz:0.42%, 702 MHz:0.05%, 810 MHz:0.02%, 918 MHz:0.02%, 1.03 GHz:0.02%, 1.13 GHz:0.01%, 1.24 GHz:0.01%, 1.35 GHz:0.01%, 1.46 GHz:0.01%, 1.51 GHz:9.34%  (21486)
analyzing CPU 1:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 0.00 ms.
analyzing CPU 2:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 0.00 ms.
analyzing CPU 3:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 0.00 ms.
```

Comment: Just some tips that may help you: try using `htop` to see how the parallel apps are using the available cores. Also `powertop` allows you to see some frequency stats.